# how to detect the start and the end of an activity in signal

Tags: matlab, time-series, signals, signal-processing

I have a data file containing timestamps - data signals. How do I detect the start of a continuous rise or the end of a continuous decrease in signal?

I wrote this code that detects wrong. It assigns two rising edges to a single activity.

Here is my code:

```
loc = (audio_file > 3000);
d_loc = [false , diff(loc)];
rising_edges_index = find(d_loc == 1);
rising_edges_index_1st = downsample(rising_edges_index,4);
falling_edges_index = find(d_loc == -1);
```

Here is the wrong result that I get from my code:

[image]

Comment: Configure your threshold better. That's difficult to do for the "general case" though, since you might have different signals every time. You can try to think up additional markers (amplitude, amplitude of the derivative, distance between start and end points ...)

Comment: Consider using a filter, like a simple moving average, to remove the small "peaks" on the right side that are being detected.